# Equivalent algorithm to round robin when there is a large quantum

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduling, round-robin

I am preparing for my on-campus placement and find this question on previous year's paper from Citrix.

#### If there is a large quantum in round robin it will be equivalent to

1. First come first serve
2. Shortest job first
3. Least recently used
4. None of these

I think answer should be '1' (First come first serve), but need better clarification or may be i am wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer,undoubtedly,has to be **(i) `First Come First Serve`**.

The reason for that being when you increase the time-quantum for processes,then each process would basically execute completely(because of longer quantum time) at the first hand. So, newer process would be added to queue, and hence, each process will execute in *its order of time of arrival* as they are inserted in the queue sequentially (Queue Is First In First Out Data Structure).

hence, all the process would run as per their order of arrival, hence, the qualified answer will be `First Come First Serve` scheduling algorithm.

Also, the `Shortest Job First` and `Least Recently Used` scheduling algorithms isn't at all similar to Round Robin Scheduling algorithm, except when they are the special cases when shortest processes come first in order as compared to longer processes. And,least recently used has nothing to do with `Round Robin Scheduling`!